# Changing link URL after every 5 visits

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following.

I have a link on my website, however I want to change that link after every 5 visits or "page refreshes" by the user and have this loop.

So for example you visit my site and the download button links to a site called "www.site1.com". You refresh my site 5 times and the download button link changes to "www.site2.com". If you refresh it for a 6th time it goes back to the original.

I have not been able to find anything searching through forums that shows what i'm trying to accomplish here. I was just experimenting with a window.onload and setInterval function that changes the link every 5 seconds. Anyway to easily transition this from every 5 seconds to every 5 page visits?

```
window.onload = function() {  
function changeURL(){
    document.getElementById("link").href = "www.site1.com";
}
setInterval(changeURL, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about storing a cookie on the users computer, essentially a counter that counts the times a user has visited your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use JavaScript [`localStorage` or `sessionStorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for this. Below is an example of your code using `localStorage`

**Example**

```
window.onload = function() 
{  

    if (localStorage.visits)
    {
        //If the value is in local storage increase it's value
        localStorage.visits = Number(localStorage.visits) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //If the value isn't in local storage set it to 0
        localStorage.visits = 0;
    }

    //Check if the number of visits is greater than 5 and set the link accordingly
    if(localStorage.visits > 5)
    {
        document.getElementById("link").href = "www.site2.com";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("link").href = "www.site1.com";
    }
}
```

This will only work if their browser supports `localStorage`. One thing to note as well, the value will not reset if they close the browser page. If you want it to reset when the page is closed, that's what `sessionStorage` is for.

One more thing to note: The user can clear `localStorage` by clearing the browser data. If you wanted something that would be even more persistent I don't believe there's a JavaScript only solution (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong about this!)

Comment: your post could be a comment, otherwise provide some examples for the OP, or just explain why using a localStorage or a Session would help him solve the problem :)

Comment: Just working on an example now, thanks for letting me know though :)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try this out. I needed some sort of direction because I had no idea how to approach this lol